# Formal proof fitch-form

Tags: first-order-logic, formal-proofs

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Hi I am trying to produce a formal proof to prove Cube(a) from premises 1 and 2 as show below. It allso shows what I got so far but Im very stuck. Am I correct that I need to produce a subproof for $\neg Cube(a)$ and $\neg Cube(b)$? Am i on a limb with my subproofs here or am I on the right track?

Edit, tried the hint below and got to this stage:

Now im not sure how to justify a rule for $12.|\neg \neg Cube(a)$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT1RA.png

Answer (score 1):

*NO*

You have corrcetly assumed $\lnot Cube(a)$ in 3 and $Cube(b)$ in 4.

From the contradiction following 5, you have to derive $\lnot Cube(b)$.

With it, by $\lor$-Intro, derive: $\lnot Cube(b) \lor Cube(c)$.

Now you have a new contradiciton (with 2) and you can conclude by *Double Negation* with $Cube(a)$.

Comment: Ok this is what it got me to: https://gyazo.com/e8ce5a61fea804bc706620e84f82148f
Did I understand correctly? If so Im not sure how to "justify" 12. $\neg \neg Cube(a)$ aka what rule to apply for it to be valid

Comment: @darrrrUC - it must be ($\lnot$I), but the details may vary according to the set of [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) rules you are using.